# Dependency for coin toss

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Hello I have a question regarding dependency.

If a fair coin is tossed 6 times, and there is two events: A-there are more heads than tails given that B-the 6th toss is a head.

We are trying to find the conditional probability. However, I am confused as to whether these events are independent or dependent. I believe they are dependent because if B is true, then there needs to be at least 3 heads in the first 5 tosses. In other words, the minimum heads in the first 5 depend on whether B is true or not.

Is this correct logic?

Comment: The definition of independence is $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ but when $B$ is an event with non-zero probability this can be rewritten as $P(A|B) = P(A)$ which is the more intuitive notion. It says that knowing B occurs does not change the probability that $A$ also occurred. In this case you can immediately intuit that knowing $B$ occurred increases the chance that $A$ occurred, so they are dependent. You can directly compute $P(A|B)$ and $P(A)$ to verify this.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

> However, I am confused as to whether these events are independent or dependent. I believe they are dependent because if B is true, then there needs to be at least 3 heads in the first 5 tosses. In other words, the minimum heads in the first 5 depend on whether B is true or not.

Good thought.

Event $A$ occurs if $B$ occurs and there at least *three* heads among the first five tosses, or if $B$ does not occur and there are at least *four* heads among the first five tosses.

Let $X$ be the count for heads among the first five tosses.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \mathsf P(X\geq 3)\\\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement) = \mathsf P(X\geq 4)\\\therefore \mathsf P(A\mid B)-\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)=\mathsf P(X=3)\end{align}$$

Since the event of throwing exactly 3 heads among the first five tosses has a non-zero probability, therefore these conditional probabilities are not equal, and so...

Comment: If the conditional probabilities are not equal...that means that A DOES depend on B. Therefore, A and B are dependent events! Thank you so much!

Comment: Indeed. Exactly so.  Also, you can now find the values if you wish.